# how do i add everying in each line between " " and put , at the end of each line using javascript

Tags: javascript, newline

okej ill try to explain. I have like 1000 personal numbers in exel. I need to put them in textarea each in new line and then with javascript i need to put each number (line) between "" and , at the end of the line. I need this exact format so i can procede with my work

```
<html>
<head>
</head>

<body>
    teskt1
    <input style="height:200px; type="text" id="1"></input>
    <p>
    <input type="button"></input>
    <p>
    tekst2
    <input style="height:200px; type="text" id="2"></input>
</body>
</body>
```

This is some html code for test but i have no idea how to do this.

Comment: So you want to convert `1,2,3,4` into `"1", "2", "3", "4"`?

Comment: Don't query like that, use real parametrised queries.

Comment: Ill put numbers like 
323
5435 
3232
each number in new line and i need to get like "323", one line "5435", next.. and so on @gurvinder372

Comment: How will you add a new line inside a textbox?

Comment: @gurvinder372 ill paste it from excel

Comment: `so i can use it for sql query`. You should not to transfer any sql query parts from browser. Just provide neccessary dataset and use it in your parametrized query.

Comment: @gurvinder372 yea i am idiot i cannot use new line in textbox ^^

Comment: `'1,2,3,4'.split(',').map(String);`

Comment: You can use `textarea`, but your initial task is completely wrong.

Comment: Maybe share with us what you would like to accomplish with this, update your question (if required); this may help us understand and provide good answers.

Comment: @CharlSteynberg okej ill try to explain. 
I have like 1000 personal numbers in exel. I need to put them in textarea each in new line and then with javascript  i need to put each number (line)  between "" and , at the end of the line. I need this exact format so i can procede with my work

Comment: @StefanMichelangeloMihajlovic can you share a fiddle of what you have tried?

Comment: @StefanMichelangeloMihajlovic :: okay, so basically you need to convert Excel spreadsheet data to HTML, then edit in browser and save in an SQL database?

Comment: @CharlSteynberg ill simple copy whole colone from excel and paste it in textarea manually i just need javascript code for formating it

Comment: @gurvinder372 ive tried nothiong since im newbie with javascript.. 
https://jsfiddle.net/7ppb3o4e/

Comment: @StefanMichelangeloMihajlovic :: that helps, thanks, the only thing we need now is some sample text and we can give you a really good answer specifically for your needs. If you can edit your question and provide info as commented by all the others, then some may "up-vote" your question and use the info to make an answer.

Comment: @StefanMichelangeloMihajlovic check this fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/gurvinder372/7ppb3o4e/1/

Comment: @gurvinder372 yea that is  what i need but with one correction. numbers should be one in each line after result is shown. Anyway thanks

Comment: @StefanMichelangeloMihajlovic try this https://jsfiddle.net/gurvinder372/7ppb3o4e/2/

Comment: @gurvinder372 thats it mate thxs a alot saved my day

Comment: @StefanMichelangeloMihajlovic you should still update your question to add the required details.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you manage to somehow put a newline inside a textbox, then try this

```
var value = document.getElementById("1").value;
var output = value.split("\n").map(function(val){return "\"" + val + "\""}).join(",")
```

[Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/gurvinder372/7ppb3o4e/2/)